# Search for element *without* a given child (where the child element is variable)

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

In SQL Server 2008 I want to identify elements that do not contain a given child element *in the case where the child element name is dynamic*. In this XML all three **li** elements contain **F1** and **F2** children, and the 2nd and 3rd **li**'s do not contain an **edges** element. I can find the **li**'s without the **edges** children if the name of the **edges** element is known beforehand - see the *exist* query below that returns 1 as it should.

```
declare @x xml = '<data>
  <li>
    <F1>ellipse</F1>
    <F2 />
    <edges/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <F1>triangle</F1>
    <F2>3</F2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <F1>square</F1>
    <F2>4</F2>
  </li>
</data>';

select @x.exist('/data/li[not(F1)]') -- returns 0, there is no li without an F1 (OK)
select @x.exist('/data/li[not(edges)]') -- returns 1, there is an li without edges (OK)
```

But if the **edges** value is not known in advance, how do I specify it using a SQL variable? I would like to code something like the following:

```
declare @ChildElement varchar(100) = 'edges';
select @x.exist('/data/li[not(sql:variable("@ChildElement"))]') -- not allowed
```

but sql:variable is not valid in this context in SQL Server. I have also tried combinations using local-name():

```
select @x.exist('/data/li[not(local-name()=sql:variable("ChildElement"))]') -- always returns 1
```

but it always returns 1. I think because there is always an **li** with a child element that is not **F1**, and there is always an **li** with a child element that is not **edges**. How I can identify just the **li** without the **edges** sub-element if **edges** is in a SQL variable? BTW I am using SQL Server 2008, although I think this applies for all SQL Server versions from 2005 up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* that your first approach does not work, as the variable is "replaced" by a string (I don't know SQL Server's XQuery capabilities well enough to explain what's going on in detail).

The second approach is querying all li elements, where the `local-name()` of the li element (current context!) equals the SQL variable – probably not what you want to do. Instead, try

```
select @x.exist('/data/li[not(./*[local-name()=sql:variable("@ChildElement")])]')
```

which tests all children instead.

Comment: Is that `./` needed? I know that the XPath in SQL Server has some quirks, but that `./` would not be needed in standard XPath.

Comment: @JLRishe no, `./` is not necessary in SQL Server. The `*` is enough. +1

Comment: Some XPath users use `./` as a way to call the reader's attention to the fact that the path is relative, not absolute.  I don't know if that was Jens Erat's intent, but it's why I often use `./` to start relative paths.

Comment: @JLRishe: what C. M. Sperberg-McQueen is saying is exactly what I'm doing. If the use of the current context is of any doubt, I'm usually explicitly denoting it. Mostly in the beginning of a query, to hint I didn't forget the root `/`.

Comment: Jens / Mikael - I just tried it (with the ./*) and it worked perfectly. I guess the * means it has to check all sub-elements in the li to make sure they don't match, which is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help - I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: This expression means more or less "all li's, which do not have any children whose name equals the SQL variabel", so yes, exactly how you described it in your comment.